# SQLServer PHP to GeoJSON

Tags: php, sql-server, geojson, spatial

Trying to write a PHP page that will return GeoJSON from MS Sql Server.

> ERROR msg:   geometry member should be object, but is an String
>   instead.

What the result is:

```
[{"type":"Feature","geometry":"\"MULTILINESTRING ((-77.083060324719384 42.15108721847372, -77.087448024528669 42.151768518696542
```

**My Code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT name, pwl_id, wbcatgry, basin, fact_sheet, geom.STAsText() as geo FROM dbo.total"; 

while ($res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $str = $res['geo'];
    $wkt = explode("((",$str);

        $msg [] = array(
                    'type' => 'Feature',            
                    'geometry' => ($res['geo']),  //<<<---  where I'm stuck.
                    // 'geometry' => json_decode($res['geo'], true),

                    'properties' => array(
                    "PWL_ID" => $res['pwl_id'],
                    "Name" => $res['name'],
```

I did this in MySQL using

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(`geom`) as geo and  'geometry' => json_decode($res['Geo'])
```

but SQL-Server doesn't have the AsGeoJSON function.

I was thinking I could grab the geo text and parse it and recreate what I need but I was hoping for a better approach and I'm not 100% sure on the parsing code.

Output would be like :

> { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PWL_ID": 18, "Name": "IN787", },
>   "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [
>   -73.781598476340562, 42.633203605299833 ], [ -73.764907547494587, 42.63285861396318 ], [ -73.75312949415769, 42.639574643901661 ] .....

Comment: what is the desired output look like for the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse them using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$string = "MULTILINESTRING ((-77.083060324719384 42.15108721847372, -77.087448024528669 42.151768518696542";

$pattern = '/((-?\d+\.\d+)\s(-?\d+\.\d+))/';

$arr = preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Which outputs

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => -77.083060324719384 42.15108721847372
        [1] => -77.087448024528669 42.151768518696542
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => -77.083060324719384 42.15108721847372
        [1] => -77.087448024528669 42.151768518696542
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => -77.083060324719384
        [1] => -77.087448024528669
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 42.15108721847372
        [1] => 42.151768518696542
    )
)
```

I organized the capture in a way that gives you an easier to use result, and it will match only pairs of coordinates.

So the ones you need are item `2` and `3`.  The rest is pretty trivial.

But I decided to be nice,

```
$len = count($matches[0]);
$coordinates = [];
for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i){
    $coordinates[] = [
        $matches[2][$i], $matches[3][$i]
    ];
}

print_r($coordinates);
```

Which outputs

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => -77.083060324719384
        [1] => 42.15108721847372
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => -77.087448024528669
        [1] => 42.151768518696542
    )
)
```

You can see the full deal here

https://3v4l.org/ecLFJ

Then you should be able to just plug that into where you need it and `json_encode` etc...

```
[["-77.083060324719384","42.15108721847372"],["-77.087448024528669","42.151768518696542"]]
```

Of course I'm only working off that little bit of input you had in the question, but it might work .

Comment: Your code looked like it worked but I couldn't get it into the right format until I saw json_encode, and that did it.

Comment: well glad I could help